# how enter a big file with 10 million row in python?

Tags: python

I want to analyze a file with 10 million users and passwords in python. File is in text format. Here are some lines of data:

```
0000    00000000
0000    00001
0000    00001111
0000    000099
0000    00009999
0000    0000w
0000    5927499
0000    634252
0000    6911703
0000    701068
```

In python I used following code to read the file:

```
f=open('10-million-combos.txt','r')
a=[]
for line in f.readlines():
    a.append(line)
```

The above code takes a few seconds to run. The data saved in the list looks like this:

```
>>>a[0:2]
['0000\t00000000\n', '0000\t00001\n']
```

To extract users and passwords I used:

```
b=[]
for i in a:
    b.append(i.split('\t'))
```

The problem is, the above code encounters a memory error after a long time and I can't separate users and passwords.

Do you have any suggestions for a solution?

Comment: Do you really need all 10Mio datasets at the same time?

Comment: @Daniel I want some information on data for example most used user and password. do i have another way?

Comment: How big is the user+password file?

Comment: @martineau the file size is 185MB with .txt format.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is you're reading each line into a Python list. How big is the file? That's how much you're putting into memory.

Do your reading and analysis in the same step so Python can garbage collect.

When you get around to the analysis part, you might want to check out [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), which is a library for data analysis.

These other answers who suggest you append to a list are going to run into the same issue with memory usage. The trick is don't build a list, do your analysis incrementally so you don't need to store 10M rows in memory.

If you are incrementing totals as you stated in your comment, and absolutely must store this in memory, you can store the values as keys in a dictionary and increment the counts.

This will still result in memory usage, so if it still crashes, your options would be:

- Persist to disk (write another file) with each iteration. Then you can read each file and grab the total, and figure out which one has the highest total with one variable. This will be slow but will trade memory usage for disk usage.
- Use a modified binary tree to prevent storing any bits twice, and add a "times" variable you can increment to  nodes:

  ab
  abc
  abc
  A {times: 0} -> B {times: 1} -> C {times: 2}

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate over each line and then do splitting according to the tab character then append the returned list to the already declared list `l` .

```
l = []
with open('10-million-combos.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        l.append(line.strip().split('\t'))
```

Comment: same problem happend.

Comment: use pandas like @Celvin suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Reading and splitting at the same time reduces the memory needed:

```
b = []
with open('10-million-combos.txt','r') as inp:
    for line in inp:
        b.append(line.strip().split('\t',1))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file is a tsv, which it appears to be, you can always use pythons `csv` module.

```
import csv


with open('10-million-combos.txt','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    for line in reader:
        user_name = line[0]
        password  = line[1]
        ....
```

This should allow you to iteratively parse through the file and do what you need to do without saving all the lines to a big list.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the other answers, you can also think about using generators which will only load data when you actually need it (think lazy evaluation):

```
def read_password_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line.strip()  # yield from f should be better starting in 3.3

def split_password(lines):
    for line in lines:
        yield line.split('\t')

a = read_password_file('10-million-combos.txt')
b = split_password(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Frankly I'm surprised that you don't have enough memory to read the 185MB file into memory, even though you're effectively creating two copies of it. Most modern systems today have GBs of memory at their disposal.

Here's something that creates only a single list-of-tuples, which will be smaller than the list-of-lists in your code.

Assuming that succeeds, there's examples of finding the most common user id and password in the dataset,

```
from collections import Counter  # dictionary subclass

records = []
with open('10-million-combos.txt', 'rU') as inf:
    for line in (line.strip() for line in inf):
        records.append(tuple(line.split('\t', 1)))

# display some of the test data read
print('Data:')
for rec in records[0:10]:
    print(rec)
print('')

# find most common user id
counter = Counter((rec[0] for rec in records))
print('most common user id: {}'.format(counter.most_common(1)[0][0]))

# find most common password
counter = Counter((rec[1] for rec in records))
print('most common password: {}'.format(counter.most_common(1)[0][0]))
```

Output:

```
Data:
('0000', '00000000')
('0002', '00001')
('0002', '00001111')
('0003', '000099')
('0004', '00009999')
('0006', '000099')
('0006', '5927499')
('0006', '634252')
('0008', '6911703')
('0009', '701068')

most common user id: 0006
most common password: 000099
```

Note: I changed the example data in your question so there would be some duplicate user_id and passwords.

Comment: this is my question too. the first part for reading file run very fast but second part encounters problem. I think this is not about memory because I create several copy of first list at same time without any problem.

Comment: If you're getting a traceback, adding it or whatever the actual error message is to your question might be helpful. It's also possible your dataset is corrupt. If there's some kind of validity checking that could be done, it could be performed while reading in each row. One simple test would be that make sure the length of each user id and password was something reasonable (i.e. in some minimum to maximum range).